# android emulator doesn't display changes

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

my android emulator doesn't display any changes. didn't change main. dart file.  do I need to delete the default main.dart file? I follow up on this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTJJsmejUOQ&t=229s)  Still working on the first five minutes of the video. just wanted to display some boxes with colours. and change the navigation bar title to 'hello'. not displaying anything. can anyone please explain what to do ?
[image]

```
**this is my app. dart code**

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'screens/location_detail/location_detail.dart';


class App extends StatelessWidget{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
     home:LocationDetail(),
   );
  }
}




  **this is my location-detal.dart file**



 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class LocationDetail extends StatelessWidget{
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar:AppBar(
            title:Text('Hello'),
          ),
    
    
          body:Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color:Colors.red,
                ),
                child:Text('hi')
    
              ),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color:Colors.green,
          ),
          child:Text('hi')
        ),
    
        Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color:Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        ),
        child:Text('hi')
    
        ),
        ],
          )
    
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Nirasha...Looks like you are not calling the app.dart class in your main.dart file.

Comment: HI! thank you. could you please say how to call that file? actually, I didn't change the default main.dart file

Comment: You can skip the app.dart file instead you can call location_details.dart in the main.dart file in the home widget i.e home:LocationDetail() .

Comment: wow, great is working. thank you so much means a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define **App** class in **Main.dart** file.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'app.dart';
        
        void main() => runApp(App());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'screens/location_detail/location_detail.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());
class App extends StatelessWidget{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
     home:LocationDetail(),
   );
  }
}




  **this is my location-detal.dart file**



 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class LocationDetail extends StatelessWidget{
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar:AppBar(
            title:Text('Hello'),
          ),
    
    
          body:Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color:Colors.red,
                ),
                child:Text('hi')
    
              ),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color:Colors.green,
          ),
          child:Text('hi')
        ),
    
        Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color:Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        ),
        child:Text('hi')
    
        ),
        ],
          )
    
        );
      }
    }
```